# How to understand the following result?

Tags: probability

I am beginning to study probability and I found the following problem:

What is the probability of to get a number twice after two throwings?

The answer was that since we have six distinct results in a fair die every possible result has $1/6$ of probability of happen and since that the result is:

$$ P(\text{rolling the same number twice in a row on a fair die} ) = (1/6)(1/6).$$

I understand till the part of the probabilities, I know that since every event is independent of the other we are applying the multiplication rule, However I would like to go more deep in the analysis and not to take this as a strict rule, I would like to understand why we had to multiply the numbers, I mean why not to sum them or divide?, I need to understand why the rule of multiplication works, I would like to receive a empirical or formal explanation of this result in order to understand more, thanks for the support.

I would like to state that my question is different since I know that if I have the scenario of only one die, thrown out in two different times my result is correct but I don't understand why we have to multiply the probabilities I know that we are using the multiplication rule but why it works? what is the reason to multiply the numbers I mean why not to divide it or to sum it, I would like to go more deep in the analysis.

Comment: That computation is not correct.  Whatever the first toss yields, there is a $\frac 16$ probability that the second will match it, so the answer is just $\frac 16$.

Comment: Try it.  Go get a die and toss it a lot.  You'll see that $\frac 1{36}$ is far too low.

Comment: Would you like an answer explaining the multiplication rule or an answer explaining this problem?

Comment: The original phrasing was a little unclear so I modified it.  Make sure that I didn't alter the meaning, especially because the problem as I (and apparently others) have interpreted it does not have answer $1/36.$  But it would be $1/36$ if the problem were to roll the same **given** number twice in a row (as opposed to just having the second roll match the first, where the first can be anything).

Comment: see this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1181129/why-are-the-probability-of-rolling-the-same-number-twice-and-the-probability-of

Comment: Well I am thinking that I need both explanations, this was very confusing for me since I think that due to the fact that the result of the first throw does not depend of the second one we have to compute that as I stated, using the multiplication rule, for me would be really helpful any explanation, I appreciate the support.

Comment: One wy to gain insight:  list all the possibilities.  It's not that bad, there are only $36$...$\{1,1\},\{1,2\}, \cdots$.  Each of these are equally probable.  Given that full list, you can read off the values you want.  Of course, eventually you want other ways to solve these problems...but nothing beats straight enumeration for understanding.

Comment: @lulu please consider the scenario of to have only one die as follows: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1181129/why-are-the-probability-of-rolling-the-same-number-twice-and-the-probability-of

Comment: Not following.  Asking to get a specific number twice is different from asking to get some number twice, right?  So of course they have different answers. If you follow my advice and list the entire sample space you'll see that only one event corresponds to "toss two $6's$" whereas six events correspond to "toss the same number twice."

Comment: @lulu I am going to change the question since it causes confusing my scenario is to get some number twice, I appreciate the support and 
patience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The probability of drawing a $1$ is $1/6$, because there is a single favorable outcome and six possible ones.

The probability of drawing two $1$s in a row is $1/36=1/6^2=(1/6)^2$ because there are now thirty-six possible outcomes. The product appears *for combinatorial reasons*. Specifically, the set of possible cases is the *Cartesian product* of the possible outcomes at the first drawing and those at the second drawing.

So just like $6^2=36$, the probabilites are multiplied, $1/6^2=(1/6)^2$. For three $1$s in a row, the probability would be $1/6^3=(1/6)^3$.

---

Now assume that you throw a die and a coin. The outcomes are from the sets $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and $\{H,T\}$. By the Cartesian product, there are $6\cdot2$ combinations and the probability of drawing a one and a head is $1/(6\cdot2)=(1/6)(1/2)$.

---

In the example with a die, probabilites aren't just multiplied, because there are several favorable cases ($6$ ways to draw the same value).

The probabilities for $1,2$ and $3$ identical drawings would be

$$\frac66=1,\\\frac6{6^2}=\frac16,\\\frac6{6^3}=\frac1{36}.$$

---

More "difficult": we throw the die twice and the coin three times and we look for equal numbers and sides.

As regards the dies, there are $6^2$ possible outcomes, and $2^3$ for the coin. Among these, $6$ combinations are favorable for the die and $2$ for the coin, forming a total of $6\cdot2$ distinct configurations (again by the Cartesian product).

Hence the probability

$$\frac{6\cdot2}{6^2\cdot2^3}=\left(\frac6{6^2}\right)\left(\frac2{2^3}\right).$$

$$\begin{matrix}
&& HHH & THH & HTH & TTH & HHT & THT & HTT & TTT \\
& 11 &\times & & & & & & &\times \\
& 12 & & & & & & & & \\
& 13 & & & & & & & & \\
& 14 & & & & & & & & \\
& 15 & & & & & & & & \\
& 16 & & & & & & & & \\
& 21 & & & & & & & & \\
& 22 &\times & & & & & & &\times \\
& 23 & & & & & & & & \\
& 24 & & & & & & & & \\
& 25 & & & & & & & & \\
& 26 & & & & & & & & \\
& 31 & & & & & & & & \\
& 32 & & & & & & & & \\
& 33 &\times & & & & & & &\times \\
& 34 & & & & & & & & \\
& 35 & & & & & & & & \\
& 36 & & & & & & & & \\
& 41 & & & & & & & & \\
& 42 & & & & & & & & \\
& 43 & & & & & & & & \\
& 44 &\times & & & & & & &\times \\
& 45 & & & & & & & & \\
& 46 & & & & & & & & \\
& 51 & & & & & & & & \\
& 52 & & & & & & & & \\
& 53 & & & & & & & & \\
& 54 & & & & & & & & \\
& 55 &\times & & & & & & &\times \\
& 56 & & & & & & & & \\
& 61 & & & & & & & & \\
& 62 & & & & & & & & \\
& 63 & & & & & & & & \\
& 64 & & & & & & & & \\
& 65 & & & & & & & & \\
& 66 &\times & & & & & & &\times \\
\end{matrix}$$

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate the support I was looking for this kind of explanation, I appreciate the support but let me analyse the answer.

Comment: I understand that the Cartesian product of the first outcomes with the second one outcomes could be stated as: $(1,1), (1,2), ... $, besides I know that the cardinality  of that set is 36, I understand that However I found a little bit weakly  the explanation about the multiplication of the probabilities since you say: So just like $62=3662=36$, the probabilities are multiplied, sorry if I am doing a lot of questions but I don't understand that fact, I appreciate your support and patience.

Comment: Thanks for the second one problem however I would like to be focus in the first one since I understand that to get the carnality of the first result with the second one we get: 36 possible results, and we get it multiplying 6 by 6 but Why do we do the same in probabilities when we apply the multiplication rule, why not to sum them or divide?.

Comment: @neo33: there should be enough information in my answer.

Comment: Yes it is very clear, I see the comparison between combinations and probability thus I am going to accept your answer, Thanks a lot for the support, I really appreciate the help.